# WSO2 API Manager API Deployments

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Is it possible to migrate all existing APIs deployed on one environment to another using using automated scripts?
Also, I need to update Production Endpoints of existing APIs while moving them to another environment.
Is this scenario possible via some automated script or we need to update endpoints manually in the new environment.

I am aware of the tool which does export/import of APIs deployed via curl command.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: The best option we found until now was the export-import tool and manually updating the backend (that  could be done through API calls), so you are right it is not really convenient

Answer (score 0):

You can put a car file directly in the conf/deployment/server folder to deploy a new version of your API (and remove the old one) This can be scripted.